# perturbed polynomial roots

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let be
$$g(t,\epsilon)=-\epsilon+at^4+O(t^5),$$ with $a>0$.
It is clear that the root of g is
$$t=-\bigg(\epsilon/a\bigg)^{1/4}+O(\epsilon^{1/2})$$
here, $t<0$ and $\epsilon \sim 0^+.$
How can I study the root of the polynomial $$k(t,\epsilon)=\epsilon(b_1t+b_2t^2+b_3t^4)+g(t,\epsilon)$$
With, $b_1, b_2,b_3$ sufficiently small number?

It is known that for $b_1<0$
$$K(0,\epsilon)=-\epsilon<0$$
$$K(-\bigg(\epsilon/a\bigg)^{1/4},\epsilon)>0$$
So $k$ has a root between $\bigg[-\bigg(\epsilon/a\bigg)^{1/4},0\bigg]$

Comment: Sorry if I don’t understand this properly, but what exactly do you mean by study, do you mean to find some bounds for the roots? If so you seem to have solved it yourself.

Comment: I would like to find the exact root, in this limit I already know, but how could I find the exact root through the root of g and a perturbation given by k.

Comment: I think exact root would look incredibly complex: since your problem is quartic, the quartic equation would technically solve it.

Comment: Use the first iterate of Newton or Halley method with $t_0=-\sqrt[4]{\frac{\epsilon }{a}}$